How long did Abraham live in Haran?
In Genesis 12:4 it states that Abraham was 75 years old when he departed from Haran, after his father Terah died there.

So Abram departed, as the LORD had directed him, and Lot went with
him. Abram was seventy-five years old when he left Haran.

How long did Abraham live in Haran with his father before moving on to Canaan?

The Bible does not say so we cannot know.

Welcome to BHSX and thanks for your joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

The Bible does not provide that information. However, we can make an educated guess based on some of the information available.
Assuming I did the math right:

If Abraham was born when Terah was 70 years old, then Abraham would
have lived in Haran for about 60 years.
If Abraham was born when Terah was 130 years old, then Abraham would
have lived in Haran for about 75 years.

There's typically two arguments: Terah was 70 or 130.
In Genesis 11:26, it is stated that Terah was 70 years old when he began to father sons, and Abraham (then called Abram) is listed first among his sons. Later, in Genesis 11:32, it is mentioned that Terah lived for 205 years, and he died in Haran. Following this, Genesis 12:4 states that Abraham was 75 years old when he left Haran.
So, Abram was 75 years old when he left Haran after his father Terah’s death. If we go back to Genesis 11:32, it’s mentioned that Terah lived 205 years. If Abram was indeed the firstborn when Terah was 70, this would mean Terah died when he was 145 years old (70 years + 75 years), which clearly contradicts the statement that Terah lived 205 years.
To reconcile this, we may assume that Abram wasn’t the firstborn but was listed first due to his significance. They propose that Abram was born when Terah was 130 years old (205 years - 75 years), which fits the statement that Terah died just as Abram left Haran at the age of 75.
Ellicott's Commentary presents both views:

From thence, when his father was dead.—In Genesis 11:26; Genesis
11:32, Terah, the father of Abraham, is said to have died at the age
of 205 years, and after he had reached the age of seventy to have
begotten Abram, Nahor, and Haran; while Abraham in Genesis 12:4 is
said to have been seventy-five years old when he departed out of
Haran. This, primâ facie, suggests the conclusion that he lived for
sixty years after his son’s departure. The explanations sometimes
given—(1) that Abraham may have been the youngest, not the eldest son of Terah, placed first in order of honour, not of time, as Shem is among the sons of Noah (Genesis 5:32; Genesis 6:10), though Japheth was the elder (Genesis 10:21); and (2) that the marriage of Abraham’s son with the granddaughter of Nahor by the youngest of his eight sons, Bethuel (Genesis 22:22), suggests some such difference of age, and that he may therefore have been born when Terah was 130, and so have
remained in Haran till his father’s death—though probable as an
hypothesis, would hardly appear so natural an explanation as that the
memory of St. Stephen or of his reporter dwelt upon the broad outlines
of the history, and was indifferent to chronological details. It is
remarkable that like difficulties present themselves in St. Paul’s own
survey of the history of Israel.

Also, see Meyer's NT Commentary which says:

Abraham was born to his father Terah when he was 70 years of age
(Genesis 11:26); and the whole life of Terah amounted to 205 years
(Genesis 11:32). Now, as Abraham was 75 years old when he went from
Haran (Genesis 12:4; Joseph. Antt. i. 7. 1), it follows that Terah,
after this departure of his son, lived 60 years. Once more, therefore,
we encounter a deviation from the biblical narrative, which is found
also in Philo, de migr. Abr. p. 415, and hence probably rests on a
tradition, which arose for the credit of the filial piety of Abraham,
who had not migrated before his father’s death.





References:





Was Terah 70 or 130 when Abram was born? (n.d.). Genesis for Ordinary People. https://www.genesisforordinarypeople.com/faq/was-terah-70-or-130-when-abram-was-born




This is useful to determine the age of Terah at Abram's birth but does not answer the question how long he lived in Haran. Abram was not born in Haran--he brought his wife with him.
